# Grouping KeyValue pairs to Dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, key-value

I have the following code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {

        var items = new List<KeyValuePair<int, User>>
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<int, User>(1, new User {FirstName = "Name1"}),
                            new KeyValuePair<int, User>(1, new User {FirstName = "Name2"}),
                            new KeyValuePair<int, User>(2, new User {FirstName = "Name3"}),
                            new KeyValuePair<int, User>(2, new User {FirstName = "Name4"})
                        };

    }
}
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Above as you can see there are multiple users for same key . Now I want to group them and convert the list object to dictionary in which the Key will be the same(1,2 as shown above) but the value will be the collection.Like this:

```
 var outputNeed = new Dictionary<int, Collection<User>>();
        //Output:
        //1,Collection<User>
        //2,Collection<User>
```

i.e they are grouped now.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you use a [**`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) instead. This data-structure is specifically intended for use as a map from keys to collections of values.

```
//uses Enumerable.ToLookup: the Id is the key, and the User object the value
var outputNeeded = items.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Of course, if you do need the dictionary (to allow for mutability perhaps), you can do something like:

```
var outputNeeded = new Dictionary<int, Collection<User>>();

foreach(var kvp in list)
{
   Collection<User> userBucketForId;

   if(!outputNeeded.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out userBucketForId)) 
   {
       // bucket doesn't exist, create a new bucket for the Id, containing the user
       outputNeeded.Add(kvp.Key, new Collection<User> { kvp.Value });
   }
   else 
   {   // bucket already exists, append user to it.
       userBucketForId.Add(kvp.Value);
   }
}
```

On another note, the`Collection<T>`class is not all that useful unless you intend to subclass it. Are you sure you don't just need a`List<User>`?

Comment: Great! Ani. Just few typos 1.kvp.Key instead of kvp.key  2 if(!outputNeeded.TryGetValue(kvp.key, out userBucketForId) closing bracket missing. But the solutions is great!

Comment: @Rocky Singh: Glad to help. Thanks for pointing the typos out; fixed

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example using LINQ's ToDictionary:

```
var output = items.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                                group => group.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList());
```

It results in a `Dictionary<int,List<User>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Given your initial variable "item", and the suggested output variable "outputNeed", this is what you need to do:

NOTE:This is not actual c#/vb code, so please change this pseudo as required (I don't have a VS Studio at hand at the moment):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, User> pair in items) 
{
    //add a new collection if this is the first time you encounter the key
    if (! outputNeed.Contains(pair.Key) 
    {
        outputNeed[pair.Key] = new ArrayList<User>());
    }
    //add the user to the matching collection
    outputNeed.Add(pair.Key, pair.User);
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var u in items)
{
    if (outputNeed.Contains(u.Key)) {
        outputNeed[u.Key].Add(u.Value);
    }
    else {
        Collection<User> a=new Collection<User>();
        a.Add(u.Value);
        outputNeed.Add(u.Key,a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

```
var items = new List<KeyValuePair<int, User>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<int, User>(1, new User { FirstName = "Name1" }),
    new KeyValuePair<int, User>(1, new User { FirstName = "Name2" }),
    new KeyValuePair<int, User>(2, new User { FirstName = "Name3" }),
    new KeyValuePair<int, User>(2, new User { FirstName = "Name4" })
};

var result = (
    from item in items
    group item.Value by item.Key into grouped
    select grouped
).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g);
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uTDBra)